# Use Monkeyrunner for test complicated app

Tags: android, python, monkeyrunner

I am new in testing android app. I select monkeyrunner way for testing android app. I don't know python but i reading this. I have a complicated app, my app have a class that extend `application` and another activity for splash and then my app go to first activity. I set `startActivity(firstActivity)` in py file, in cmd shows my app run correctly and monkeyimage take a screenshot from my screen (home screen) but my app not run and not shows firstActivity in my device phone! i run `startActivity(splash)` but again not shows on my screen. Why? I test this in a simple app with one activity, when i run `startActivity(firstActivity)` on the screen, i see my simple app. How can solve this problem? and How can i go to another activity with monkeyrunner? I mean from application go to splash and from splash go to firstActivity?!

Thanks for your advices!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use

```
adb logcat
```

to see the package and the starting Activity name..
if you find these two for example package='pck.package' and activity = '.Main'
then what you should write in your code, is:

```
package = 'pck.package'
activity = '.Main'
runComponent = package+'/'+activity
device.startActivity(component=runComponent)
```

in other words, you must use the package name as well in your code

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for reply. I know how can start an activity with Monkeyrunner but i want to know, how can run first my class that extend 'application' and how can switch between activity.

Comment: To be honest I have not yet understand what do you want to do... Maybe you should post some code of your class... :/

Comment: You application class is not visible, so from monkeyrunner perspective, it doesn't exist.

Comment: You mean my application class is not exist and for this i can't see this? but this class is exist!

Comment: Have you declared your class?